# Umbraco, Macintosh and some working blog software

Tags: macos, umbraco-blog

I have a website that is using Umbraco as it's CMS.  Everything is working great on a PC.  Am able to use Windows Live Writer to create blogs with no problems at all.  My problem comes when the Macintosh users try to blog.  I have tried loads of different software packages, MarsEdit, Bloggo etc. but none seem to work.  Has anyone had any joy with blog software on a Macintosh using Umbraco as the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be slightly useful:
http://www.geardiary.com/2009/06/22/mac-blog-clients-the-search-is-over/

(Qumana Blog Manager)